# How to traverse a sorted list in single for loop?

Tags: java

I want to traverse a sorted list. If list contains name A then give first A.If it does not contain then give first B present.

I had done this using two for loop.

```
for(Product product : productList) 
{
   if(product.getName().equals("A")) 
   {
      add = product.getName() + product.getDob();
    break;
   }
}

if (add == null)
    {
        for(Product product : productList) 
        {
            if(product.getName().equals("B")) 
            {     
              add = product.getName() + product.getDob();
              break;
            }
        }
}
```

I expect this solution in single for loop.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: What is the sorting criteria of your list?

Comment: @Ricola....Product class contains two variable one is dateOfOpening and other variable is Name. Sorting criteria is dateOfOepning is ascending order. Already sorted the list

Answer (score 1):

Check both conditions in the same loop:

```
for(Product product : productList) 
{
   if(product.getName().equals("A")) 
   {
      add = product.getName() + product.getDob();
    break;
   }
   else if(product.getName().equals("B")) 
   {
      addB = product.getName() + product.getDob();
   }
}

if(add == null)
{
add = addB
}
```

Comment: You don't need a separate `addB` variable. There is also a bug in your implementation, you will get the first A or the **last** B, instead of the first B.

Answer (score 0):

If you find an A, return early. If you find a B, store it in a variable in case you don't find any As.

```
public Product getFirstAorB()
{
    Product firstB = null;
    for(Product product : productList) 
    {
        if ("A".equals(product.getName())) {
            return product;
        }
        else if (firstB == null && "B".equals(product.getName())) {
            firstB = product;
        }
    }
    return firstB;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an additional arrya in which indicate what are you looking for. For example:

```
String [] cr = {"C", "A", "B"};
for(Product product : productList){
    for (String pr : cr)
        if(product.getName().equals(pr)){
            add = product.getName() + product.getDob();
       }
    }
```

In this case you need only one loop to check your productList.